# Numpy Cut 2d array by row

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D array like this:

```
a = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]]
```

is there a way to cut them per row in ah pythonic way?
So the result will be:

```
[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4],[5,5],[6,6],[7,7],[8,8],[9,9],[10,10]]
```

Comment: Remark: your a is not an np.array in your code and you will need to make it one when using the transpose-approach by akash, which i recommend! The pure python way would be based on ```zip```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `.T`

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]])
a.T
array([[ 1,  1],
   [ 2,  2],
   [ 3,  3],
   [ 4,  4],
   [ 5,  5],
   [ 6,  6],
   [ 7,  7],
   [ 8,  8],
   [ 9,  9],
   [10, 10]])
```

Comment: Okey, that very simple;)